# mouseenter and mouseout firing simultaneously on hover

Tags: jquery

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$('h1').mouseenter(function(event) {
    console.log("in");
    $('.cursor:nth-child(2)').animate({height: "60px", width: "60px"}, 300)
});
$('h1').mouseleave(function(event) {
    console.log("out");
    $('.cursor:nth-child(2)').animate({height: "30px", width: "30px"}, 300)
});
```

The relevant CSS is here:

```
.cursor:nth-child(2) {
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

And the relevant HTML is an H1 tag. What I expect to happen is straightforward - the .cursor div to expand while the cursor is hovering over an H1 element, and shrink back down to size when it isn't.

However, when I hover over the element the console continuously logs (in) and (out), hundreds of times. The same thing happens with .hover().

Here's a link to a Codepen: https://codepen.io/DrSuave/pen/BqrxER

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note that you can do pretty much everything you do in CodePen on Stack Overflow. [edit] your question and click on the icon that has a page with `<>` in it.

Comment: At this moment, Codepen is out of service (`502`), which is precisely the reason that a minimal, complete, verifiable example needs to be **in the question itself**, as @HereticMonkey points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two Issues

**1. The hundreds of console logs**

A `mousemove` event can fire *hundreds of times* just from a short amount of sustained mouse movement...

> The frequency rate of events while the pointing device is moved is implementation-, device-, and platform-specific, but multiple consecutive mousemove events SHOULD be fired for sustained pointer-device movement, rather than a single event for each instance of mouse movement.

Each and every time it fires, you're adding *another* `mouseenter` and *another* `mouseleave` event. The reason your `in` and `out` are logging hundreds of times is because you've repeatedly attached the same events hundreds of times.

The **simple solution** is to move your `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event handlers *outside* of your `$(document).mousemove(function() { ... })`.

---

**2. The cursor blocking click/hover events**

Your `cursor` is blocking your mouse events, so you'll want to add `pointer-events: none` to it. This will allow mouse events (like `hover`, `click`, etc) to pass *through* that element as if it weren't there.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer combined with Andrei's solved the problem.

Comment: You're right - that's a more graceful way to deal with it. Double thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your heading title always stays on top. And also add a transparent background to heading element.

**CSS**

```
...
h1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://codepen.io/todorutandrei/pen/YJaOzg?editors=1111

Comment: Thank you. Your answer combined with Tyler's solved the problem.